# What is the opposite of a simulacrum?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of a simulacrum, in the sense of an image, effigy or representation?

I am looking for a word to describe the original flesh and blood person represented by a statue.

Comment: Antonyms for this word are easily found via online thesauruses.  The most obvious choice would be "original."  What about this word or any of the others listed is inadequate?  What research have you done to answer this question?

Comment: @JBH Perhaps I could've phrased it better. But "the original of a statue" doesn't sound right at all. Put it this way. A statue is a simulacrum of a person. A person is the ___? of a statue.

Comment: @MRichards In the context of a statue, _model_ would be the obvious choice. I doubt there’s a one-size-fits-all solution here that will fit all contexts, though.

Comment: I thought about model but it doesn't fit statues that are modelled on a living person but represent a dead person or a person otherwise not present. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It would help if you gave us an example sentence of how you want to use this word and why just naming the person doesn't suffice. Are you looking for a word that infers the existence of the image from the way you refer to the original/model without explicitly mentioning it?

Comment: @Spagirl "... tearing down the statues whose [models/inspirations/etc] were flawed mortals."

Comment: @MRichards Ah, in that case, is there any reason 'subjects' doesn't fit the bill? (which is covered in Ruble.31's answer)

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, I suppose that would be the best fit. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggested "original," you could also use "subject," "inspiration,"or "archetype."